# Trying to ping devices from my Android 4 smartphone

Tags: android, wifi, ping, router

I am trying to ping to a device connected to my WiFi router, it is a KNXnet/IP-router. I use the Android App "Ping" to send out packets.

Some settings:

IP address of my WiFi router (TP-LINK 3420): 169.254.96.1, subnet: 255.255.255.0

Settings KNX IP router: IP: 169.254.96.33, subnet: 255.255.255.255, gateway: 169.254.96.1

My smartphone has the local IP 169.254.96.103

If I try to ping the WiFi router it works, if I try to connect to the KNX router I do not recevice any answer.

The firewall of the WiFi router is deactivated and there is no MAC or IP filtering used.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DHCP hasn't assigned you a valid IP address. 169.254.xxx.xxx is a dummy address which means that you don't have a real one (http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/sep/24/169-254-0-0-addresses-explained/). Either fix whatever issue is with DHCP or assign a static IP addresses.